# Product of Connected Spaces (2)

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If $Y$ and $Z$ are connected,
is $Y \times Z$ path connected?
I cannot find a counter example. Some help please.

Comment: Are $Y$ and $Z$ supposed to be _path_ connected, as opposed to simply connected?  (Otherwise taking $Y$ to be any connected but not path-connected space, and $Z$ to be a singleton space would provide a counterexample.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer are you related to Daniel Fischer?

Answer (score 3):

If $Y$ and $Z$ are path connected, so is $Y\times Z$. Just take the product of paths. If $Y$ is not path connected then $Y\times Z$ cannot be path connected, otherwise the projection of a path in $Y\times Z$ would be a path in $Y$.